# Overloading templates and argument matching - possible typo in C++ Primer?

Tags: c++, templates

Just want to confirm if this is a typo or if I don't understand how function template parameter matching works. Given these two function definitions:

```
// print any type we don't otherwise handle
template <typename T> string debug_rep(const T &t)
{
  ostringstream ret; // see 8.3
  ret << t; // uses T's output operator to print a representation of t
  return ret.str(); // return a copy of the string to which ret is bound
}

// print pointers as their pointer value, 
// followed by the object to which the pointer points
// NB: this function will not work properly with char*; see 16.3
template <typename T> string debug_rep(T *p)
{
  ostringstream ret;
  ret << "pointer: " << p;       // print the pointer's own value
  if (p)
    ret << " " << debug_rep(*p); // print the value to which p points
  else
    ret << " null pointer";      // or indicate that the p is null
  return ret.str(); // return a copy of the string to which ret is bound
}
```

Consider the following call:

```
const string *sp = &s;
cout << debug_rep(sp) << endl;
```

Here both templates are viable and both provide an exact match:

- `debug_rep(const string* &)`, the instantiation of the first
  version of the template with `T` bound to `const string*`
  **Is this a mistake? Shouldn't `T` be bound to `string*` since the `const` is in the function parameter already**
- `debug_rep(const string*)`, the instantiation of the second
  version of the template with `T` bound to `const string`.

My first question is in bold, in the above. Follow up question: If this is not a typo, and `T` is bound to `const string*`, wouldn't that imply we have `debug_rep(const const string* &)` (for the first function), not `debug_rep(const string* &)` (I'm simply replacing `T` with `const string*`). If it does not imply `debug_rep(const const string* &)`, then where did the `const` in the function parameter go? What am I not getting?...

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `T` is `const string*`, and hence `const T&` is `const string* const &`.

Comment: (That's why some people prefer "const on the right" ordering: `T const &`, `string const *`, etc. Then it compos neatly.)

Comment: Ohh! I see it now. Because the `const` in the function parameter is a top level `const`, the one being passed (and is retained) is a low-level `const`. Low level `const` are retained when passing a pointer or reference type. It's much clearer now that you mentioned the position of the `const`, something in my head clicked :) (Off topic, but I've only ever seen these terms used in C++ Primer...)

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, I don't know how to accept your answer. I think it's because it's in  comment.

Comment: Wait, so there is a typo in the book then? `debug_rep(const string* &)` is supposed to be `debug_rep(const string* const &)` - this makes more sense, going by your comment.

Comment: No, there's no typo. The book is correct that `T` is deduced as `const string*`, and I added by way of explanation that therefore `const T&` is `const string* const&`.

Comment: (You can't accept comments as answers. Someone would have to actually post an answer. I'm a little too lazy to do that right now :-S.)

Comment: I understand that (thanks to you!) "therefore `const T&` is `const string* const&` ". Thus, this means that the first function, `debug_rep(const T &t)` is deduced (is this the correct word?) to `debug_rep(const string* const&)`, not `debug_rep(const string* &)` (as stated in the first bullet point). So the book is not wrong that `T` is deduced as `const string*`, but it got the overall function parameter wrong. Is this correct? Sorry for being repetitive, thanks again for your help, I appreciate this a lot.